# MVC 5 - oAuth with Owin with custom database

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I'm creating a new MVC application, on the new Owin platform.

I would like to leverage all of the oAuth login providers provided, however, I would like to use my own data store & access methods.

Is it possible to do this without using Entity Framework?

The very first line in `ConfigureAuth` is

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
```

I was really expecting to just be able to implement an interface such as

```
IUserStore
    .CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    .DeleteAsync(ApplicationUser user)
```

And inject it.

Is this the way to do this? Nothing seems to work at all if you remove the auto-generated `DbContext` - which I don't want referenced in my presentation layer at all.

This whole thing just seems awful.

Are there any good 3rd-party oAuth libraries for MVC5?

Any advice would be *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: I would also like to know if anyone has done this using the OWIN platform. I have instead had to opt for DotNetOpenAuth and a custom database solution. It required extra coding, but was worth it in terms of the overall control of the database structure.